# Map with multiple keys in C++

Tags: c++, key, std, stdmap, compound-key

I want to store data by both, their name and their index. In other words, I want to map `string` names to objects and also give them a custom order.

What I came up with first is a `std::vector` of pairs of the `string` key and the object. The order was given by the position in the vector.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, object> >
```

But this approach seems to be suboptimal since it doesn't automatically check for the uniqueness of `string` names. Moreover it feels wrong to group the objects by their order first, because logically their first order distinction is the name.

I need a data structure that allows access by both name and index.

```
std::magic<std::string, unsigned int, object> collection;

// access by either string or unsigned int key
collection.insert("name", 42, new object());
collection["name"]
collection[42]
```

Is there a data structure for this use case already? If not, how can I put one together, preferably using the standard library? Also I would like a way to insert new elements at the position after a given element without moving all further elements around.

Comment: You need two `std::map` objects.

Comment: @n.m. I don't need to order by string name. So basically I need a `std::vector` for order and an `std::unordered_map` for names. But my question is if there is already a solution or at least a preferable way.

Comment: `unordered_map` is a possibility if you are using C++11. For the indices, a choice between `vector` and `map`/`unordered_map` is dictated by what should happen when you remove things from your collection. If you don't care about stable indices, you can use `vector`. I think two containers *is* the preferable way.

Comment: Maybe http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Look at `boost::multiindex`, it was made just for this purpose.

Comment: @Chad That's what I was looking for! If you would write an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: As of ten years later, is boost:multiindex still the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost provides a set of containers just for this purpose, see:  [boost::multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to write a solution using std library, as requested in the original post. I will not have access to boost in my resource-constrained system. I've drafted a two-map system mentioned in the comments.

A big downside is that you'll have to wrap each public function that a std::map or std::vector normally offers, and my wrapper might not be as optimal.

But, this is a start. Let me know of improvements to my answer in the comment, and I'll edit the response when I can

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Object
{
    int val;
};

template <typename T>
class MultiKeyMap
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint> nameToIdMap;
    std::unordered_map<uint, T> idToValMap;

public:
    T& find(const std::string& name)
    {
        return find(nameToIdMap[name]);
    }

    T& find(const uint id)
    {
        return idToValMap[id];
    }

    T& operator[](const std::string& name) { return find(name); }
    T& operator[](const uint id) { return find(id); }

    void insert(uint id, const std::string& name, T&& val)
    {
        nameToIdMap[name] = id;
        idToValMap[id] = val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MultiKeyMap<Object> mkmap;
    mkmap.insert(1, "one", Object{11});
    mkmap.insert(2, "two", Object{22});

    std::cout << "key=1: val=" << mkmap[1].val << "\n";
    std::cout << "key='one': val=" << mkmap["one"].val << "\n";
    std::cout << "key=2: val=" << mkmap[2].val << "\n";
    std::cout << "key='two': val=" << mkmap["two"].val << "\n";
}
```